# Copy a datagridview cell value to another cell in the same datagridview automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my datagridview, i got 4 columns, when the user gives some value to the first row then I want to take the `1st row 4th cell value and put it to the 2nd Row 3rd cell`like that I have to apply for all the rows(Please see the image ). In some case I'll have only 2 rows and the max i'll have 4 rows.

The below method it works, but when i tested with 2 or 3 rows it doesn't work..obviously 3rd and 4th is doesn't exist.

What should i do?? Is there a better way of doing this??

Here i coded for the max 4 rows.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
             var value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = value1;

            var value2 = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value = value2;

            var value3 = dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value = value3;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this you should handle `CellEndEdit`, and definitely don't hardcode row indices.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 3)
        return;
    int nextRowIndex = e.RowIndex + 1;
    int lastRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    if (nextRowIndex <= lastRowIndex)
    {
        var value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an another problem, i got cell validating & cell validated event..when i use your method or my method and leave the cursor in the cell and i try to open an another file.. i'm getting an error `argument out of range exception unhandled' Do i have to call cellEndEdit method??? Thank you.

Comment: I dont get it! How do you open a file, and what is the relation between opening a file and your DataGridView?

Comment: If i leave the cursor in the cell and open another file through file open...i'm getting the above error. if remove the cursor and open another file..then i don't get any error. Once i have entered something in the cell, it's not reflecting immediately..i have to click twice to reflect..is that normal??

Comment: You can put this code in CellValidating or CellValidated events, it works fine; But these events will fire every time user navigates from a cell to another while CellEndEdit just fires when user changes value of a cell.